# Accessibility tool JAWS vs NVDA for flex air application

Tags: apache-flex, air, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I have a flex AIR application and trying to add accessibility to it.  I tried to use JAWS demo version doesn't seem to work well at all.  It doesn't detect the names of my text input all the time and all the buttons, I need to click on it in order to hear what it is.  Is there a setting in JAWS that I need to fix in order to make it right or is it because it is a demo version?
I tried the open source NVDA and it works great and I don't need to add anything onto my application and it seems to sound out everything when I even do a mouse over onto the button or the textinput area.
The thing is I cannot say my application only works with NVDA tool.
Anyone has similar problem before?

Also, I have this application port to mobile AIR app.  Any chance that accessibility will work on an android device? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use JAWS demo version doesn't seem to work well at all.

I have to mention that using the demo of JAWS for testing purposes is forbidden, as outlined in their User agreement, which is why I suggested using NVDA for testing in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729376/desktop-air-application-accessibility).

> I need to click on it in order to hear what it is

JAWS is for people with vision impairments, so no to very limited mouse use. Try both using <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the arrow keys to navigate the app. If you can see that focus in inside a textbox, but cannot type, try pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate forms mode.

> I even do a mouse over onto the button or the textinput area

NVDA, I think, asks you if you want elements that the mouse touches to be announced when you install it. Some people with vision impairments use the mouse to find stuff, but these users are usually considered to be experts or advanced users. By using the navigation method I mentioned above, you test for basic and advanced users, as well as, you can see the interaction for people who don't use the mouse because of a mobility disability or something like a repetitive stress injury.

You may have ten form elements on the page, using this method, you'll see if the order of the text boxes is what you expected.